# Are digital sound effects haram?

Tags: music

Is it permissible to listen to or make digital sounds? Note that these digital sounds are made with computer without musical instruments and they are sometimes very pleasing to hear. Although they are not really music but may sound like some musical instruments. Examples of these sounds are beep sound, white noise, user interface sound, whoosh sound, robot sound, glitch sound, loading sound, warning or error sound in windows, keybad tones in mobile phone, notification sound etc. These are pleasing to hear but they don't cause you to dance like music. They are also used in many programs. If it is permissible to make these sound then to what extent would it be permissible?

Example of this kind of sound -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwnzygvHhGM (Glitch sound)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qokt65f20o (User Interface sound)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPfCZhvj1Ng (Beep sound)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMfPqeZjc2c&t=10s (White noise)

Comment: Please edit your original question if you want to add some more information, to keep the sbject together.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the rulings, the first thing that matters is which Islamic religion are you from and which world do you follow ?! Because such rulings have different jurisprudential rulings according to different Islamic religions.
However, the jurisprudential rule of music in Shiite Islam is such that most Shiite scholars do not consider music absolutely forbidden, but different music has different rules.

Most scholars forbid music that is suitable for dance parties and corruption. Or music that raises the excitement to the point that the intellect can not work properly.
Therefore, when you say that these musics or sounds are not for dancing and do not cause much excitement in you, then these are not part of haram music and it is permissible to listen to them.